# Though i am passing an object but post method returning an empty object in req.body

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

#expressJs
#nodeJs
i am a posting a data from my react form but here when i calling post method it returning posts but not `returning` the object that i have already filled. it only returns empty object.

I am expecting the object that i have passed by form in frontend . I need the object which i passed in frontend.
how can i solve it?

```
const express=require('express')
const app=express()
const cors=require('cors')
const port=process.port|| 5000
const bodyParser=require('body-parser')

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

const students=[
    {name:'salim',age:15},
    {name:'rafik',age:16},
    {name:'atik',age:17},
]
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.send(students)
})
app.post('/post',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log('post hited');
})
app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log(`Listening Port is ${port}`);
})
```

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [user,setUser]=useState()
  useEffect(()=>{
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/')
    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then(data=>console.log(data))
  },[])
  const handleSubmit=(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    const form=e.target
    const name=form.name.value
    const age=form.age.value
    const newUser={name,age}
    console.log(newUser);
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/post',{
      method:'POST',
      header:{
        'Content-type':'application/json',
      },
      body:JSON.stringify(newUser)
    })
    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then(data=>console.log(data))
    // form.reset()

  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form action="" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" name='name' />
        <input type="text" name='age' />
        <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Your post method handler currently doesn't respond to the request _at all_.

Comment: you post content-type in` application/json` but use `urlencoded` to parse body.  you need to use `app.use(express.json());`

Answer (score 0):

You have to set middleware for the JSON body while initializing express. Example as follows -

```
app.use(express.json());
```

put this in your backend file where you added other middleware. Click [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/express-js-express-json-function/) for example.